# any efficient alternative for GridSeachCV to find best hyperparams in deep NN in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, keras, deep-learning

In my image classification experiment, I want to find hyperparams for CNN model, and I used `RandomizedSearchCV` to find its possible best hyperparams but I got following argument error which I can't figure out why.

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)
>
> in ()
> 41
> 42 model, pred = algorithm_pipeline(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, model,
> ---> 43                                 param_grid, cv=5, scoring_fit='neg_log_loss')
> 44
> 45 print(model.best_score_)
>
> 32 frames
>
> /usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
> 167                     reductor = getattr(x, "**reduce_ex**", None)
> 168                     if reductor:
> --> 169                         rv = reductor(4)
> 170                     else:
> 171                         reductor = getattr(x, "**reduce**", None)
>
> TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects

I looked into possible solution for this sort of error in `SO` but still error didn't go away.

Here is part of my code including error report in [this colab](https://gist.github.com/jerry-shad/135575b180428102b6210ebcc999e60f). I don't understand what's wrong with my attempt. can anyone point me out how to get rid of this error? Thanks

**my current attempt**

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, GridSearchCV

def algorithm_pipeline(X_train_data, X_test_data, y_train_data, y_test_data, 
                       model, param_grid, cv=2, scoring_fit='neg_mean_squared_error',
                       do_probabilities = False):
    gs = RandomizedSearchCV(
        estimator=model,
        param_distributions=param_grid, 
        cv=cv, 
        n_jobs=-1, 
        scoring=scoring_fit,
        verbose=2
    )
    fitted_model = gs.fit(X_train_data, y_train_data)
    
    if do_probabilities:
      pred = fitted_model.predict_proba(X_test_data)
    else:
      pred = fitted_model.predict(X_test_data)
    
    return fitted_model, pred
```

please see whole code including error report in [this colab](https://gist.github.com/jerry-shad/135575b180428102b6210ebcc999e60f)

I don't understand where is error come from. how to get rid of above error? Any idea?

**update**:

I also tried bayesian optimization approach by using `scikit-optimize`package, here is [my attempt in this colab](https://gist.github.com/jerry-shad/27a0cac1611e4a0eaa66ce17e347969c), but I got also error.

Can anyone help me how to make this work either `GridSearchCV` or `Bayesian-optimization attempt` in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jerry-shad/27a0cac1611e4a0eaa66ce17e347969c)? Any possible help to make this workable? Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: @mujjiga thanks, I fixed broken link, please see my updated post. I tried your attempt down below, and it was too much time consuming for very deep NN. Do you have other efficient attempt for hyperparam optimization? Do you mind to take a look [my attempt-1](https://gist.github.com/jerry-shad/135575b180428102b6210ebcc999e60f) and [my attempt-2](https://gist.github.com/jerry-shad/27a0cac1611e4a0eaa66ce17e347969c)? Could you post your updated promising output in your gist or colab? Thank you!!!

Comment: @mujjiga which colab are you looking at? I exactly did like this but after 1st epoch optimization is failed. Here is [my recent colab](https://gist.github.com/jshayiding/385ec5a600bc98bb10ee26bf654887ce). Any possible thoughts to fix this up? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @mujjiga thanks for correcting, it worked. Why every optimization run is started randomly? Do we have to keep it stable?  Does it affect optimization process? How can we put `learning_rate`, `kernel_size` as optimized parameter in your attempt? Any idea?

Comment: Regarding the other question, yes we can let the framework identify from a range using for example`{"name": "lr", "type": "range", "bounds": [1e-6, 0.4], "log_scale": True}` AX is very powerful, please read the AX documentation to understand its full capabilities.

Comment: @mujjiga could you how `learning_rate` is going to be optimized as parameter? I got string error. Plus, how can we determine number of total trails depends on training data we have? any possible update?  Thanks

Comment: Updated the answer to show how to use `lr`. Depending on how much time each epoch takes you can set the total trials. Any value between 50 to 100 for a big dataset/model is good enough.

Comment: @mujjiga can we make plot for whole optimization process? Is `ax` provides any utilities how is optimization done with plotting? Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes AX has utility methods for plotting.  Check this https://ax.dev/tutorials/tune_cnn.html Example is for pytorch but the plotting code is just python code so it will work with keras too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219750/discussion-between-beyond-inifinity-and-mujjiga).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sklearn `GridSearchCV` will not work directly on keras model. You have to use keras scikit_learn wrapper to make it work with sklearn apis. For example, a keras model has to be wrapped using `KerasClassifier`

#### Sample Code

Code documented inline.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import numpy
from sklearn import datasets 

# Load data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# Create a function that returns a model
# You can use additional parameters to this function,
# which will be passed by the GridSearchCV, for parameter tuning.
def get_model(opt, activation):
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=4, activation=activation))
  model.add(Dense(4, activation=activation))
  model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
  
  model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model

# Wrap it to make it sklearn compatible
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=get_model)

# Create the parameter grid
param_grid = dict(epochs=[1,2,3], opt = ['rmsprop', 'adam'], activation=['relu', 'tanh'])

# finally run 
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid)
result = grid.fit(X, y)

# Get the gridsearch best parameters
print(f"Best score: {result.best_score_}, Parameters: {result.best_params_}")
```

Output:

```
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2447 - accuracy: 0.4167
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 1.4246 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.9505 - accuracy: 0.2500
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.8273 - accuracy: 0.6667
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.0976 - accuracy: 0.4167
............... LOG TRUNCATED........
Epoch 1/2
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.1047 - accuracy: 0.3333
Epoch 2/2
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.0931 - accuracy: 0.3333
Best score: 0.5000000089406967, Parameters: {'activation': 'relu', 'epochs': 2, 'opt': 'adam'}
```

Or for `RandomizedSearchCV` use

```
grid = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=model, param_distributions=param_grid)
```

### Edit 1

## Parameter tuning using bayes optimization from AX framework

code is documented inline

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from ax.service.managed_loop import optimize
from keras.optimizers import Adam, RMSprop


# Seed to for reproducible results
np.random.seed(3)

# Load data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# Train test split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=3)

# Create a function that returns a model
def get_model(opt, activation, dropout, lr):
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=4, activation=activation))
  model.add(Dropout(dropout))
  model.add(Dense(4, activation=activation))
  model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
  
  if opt == 'adam':
    optimizer = Adam(lr=lr)
  elif opt == 'rmsprop':
    optimizer = RMSprop(lr=lr)

  model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model

# Method that creates a model and trains it based on the hyper parameters
# Once the model trained we evaluate it on test data and return the accuracy
# This accuracy value will be used by the Bayes optimization
# to identify the next set of hyper-parameters to be used. 
def train_evaluate(parameterization):
    acc = 0
    mymodel = get_model(opt=parameterization["opt"], activation=parameterization["activation"], dropout=parameterization["dropout"], lr=parameterization["lr"])
    mymodel.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=parameterization["epochs"], verbose=0)
    acc = mymodel.evaluate(X_test, y_test)[1]
    print(parameterization, acc)
    del mymodel
    return acc

# Finally run the Bayes optimization
best_parameters, values, experiment, model = optimize(
     parameters=[
                 {"name": "opt", "type": "choice", "values": ['adam', 'rmsprop']},
                 {"name": "activation", "type": "choice", "values": ['relu', 'tanh']},
                 {"name": "dropout", "type": "choice", "values": [0.0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 0.99]},
                 {"name": "epochs", "type": "choice", "values": [10, 50, 100]},
                 {"name": "lr", "type": "range", "bounds": [1e-6, 0.4], "log_scale": True}
                ],
    evaluation_function=train_evaluate,
    objective_name="acc",
     # total trails. Based on the dateset size you can change this value. This value is used to determine the number of exploration and exploitation steps. 
    total_trials=30,
    )

# Get the best hyper parameters
data = experiment.fetch_data()
df = data.df
best_arm_name = df.arm_name[df["mean"] == df["mean"].max()].values[0]
best_arm = experiment.arms_by_name[best_arm_name]

print(best_parameters)
print(best_arm)
```

Ouptput

```
[INFO 08-12 13:23:03] ax.modelbridge.dispatch_utils: Using Sobol generation strategy.
[INFO 08-12 13:23:03] ax.service.managed_loop: Started full optimization with 30 steps.
[INFO 08-12 13:23:03] ax.service.managed_loop: Running optimization trial 1...
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.8532 - accuracy: 0.6579
[INFO 08-12 13:23:04] ax.service.managed_loop: Running optimization trial 2...
{'opt': 'rmsprop', 'activation': 'tanh', 'dropout': 0.75, 'epochs': 50} 0.6578947305679321
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 1.2705 - accuracy: 0.2895
[INFO 08-12 13:23:05] ax.service.managed_loop: Running optimization trial 3...
{'opt': 'adam', 'activation': 'relu', 'dropout': 0.99, 'epochs': 10} 0.28947368264198303
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.3625 - accuracy: 0.9737
[INFO 08-12 13:23:06] ax.service.managed_loop: Running optimization trial 4...
............... LOG TRUNCATED, RUN for 3 minutes........
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.9861 - accuracy: 0.5000
[INFO 08-12 13:23:29] ax.service.managed_loop: Running optimization trial 29...
{'opt': 'adam', 'activation': 'tanh', 'dropout': 0.0, 'epochs': 10} 0.5
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.9654 - accuracy: 0.3158
[INFO 08-12 13:23:30] ax.service.managed_loop: Running optimization trial 30...
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 1.1320 - accuracy: 0.6842
{'opt': 'adam', 'activation': 'tanh', 'dropout': 0.99, 'epochs': 10} 0.6842105388641357
{'opt': 'adam', 'activation': 'tanh', 'dropout': 0.0, 'epochs': 100}
Arm(name='8_0', parameters={'opt': 'adam', 'activation': 'tanh', 'dropout': 0.0, 'epochs': 100})
```

As can be seen from logs the best hyper parameters for this sample are

```
parameters={'opt': 'adam', 'activation': 'tanh', 'dropout': 0.0, 'epochs': 100})
```

Finally you can train a model with best parameters using

```
train_evaluate(best_parameters)
```